# Cambiar color de botón "save" de Pinterest

Tags: javascript, jquery, botón, img

Actualmente tengo el siguiente problema:
Tengo el widget de Pinterest que hace aparezca en botón "save": https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/widgets/save/? para todas las imágenes al poner el cursor encima de ellas. Pero se muestra de color negro.
¿Existe alguna manera de ponerlo en rojo en lugar de negro?
Apreciaría mucho cualquier idea, gracias.

Este es el script que utilizo:

```
<script async defer data-pin-hover="true" data-pin-tall="true" data-pin-round="true" src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno primero tendrías que sobrescribir el css, y darle tu propio estilo, algo como esto podría ser de ayuda para comenzar, pruébalo.

```css
span[class^='PIN']{
background: #d20909 url('https://cdn.worldvectorlogo.com/logos/pinterest-1.svg') 3px 100% no-repeat !important;
background-size: 14px 14px !important;
background-position-y: 3px !important;
}
```

```html
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    async defer
    src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"
></script>
<a href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/" data-pin-do="buttonBookmark">
</a>
```